# What does it mean when the shape of input images is (600,64,64,3)?

Tags: cnn, convolution, deep-learning

While attempting an assignment, I found that shape of the input image was (600,64,64,3).
I thought 3 stood for the number of channels but it's listed as the 4th dimension.
What does this mean?
This is in reference to convolutional neural networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth dimension is because it is referring to either the full dataset(train/test) Or an individual batch.

600 - *Number of images in the dataset or batch*

64 x 64 - *Size of each image*

3 - *Number of channels*

Answer (score 1):

600 can be  the number of  images of shape 64x64x3 and not  only one image.